# Access tokens for Alexa and Google Home

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, dialogflow-es, google-home

Where are tokens stored when account linking is completed for Google Home and Alexa?

For example, if I add an Alexa skill for service XYZ and link my XYZ account via the Alexa app, the authorization service will return a token to use for authentication.

I would like to know where this token is stored as it may raise a security issue. Is it stored locally on the device? Or in the Amazon servers?

Answer (score 1):

- Amazon stores account linked tokens (access and refresh tokens) in their servers (not on the echo device)
- You can not reach this tokens table, but when the user use your skill, Alexa will send current access token of the user to your skill function (for ex: lambda)

In short, if your skill has account linking, then skill developer has to trust Amazon to store tokens securely

> The Alexa service stores this token and includes it in requests sent to your skill’s service.

doc: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: hi μ-muthupandian , I added the doc into the answer. I you think the answer is satisfied, please vote up